# Using R markdown, is there a way to fix the row names of a scrollable (html), kable table, similar to the scroll_box function fixes the header row?

Tags: html, scroll, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I have a very wide html kable table, that I've created with R markdown, and I can scroll through it in every direction. The header row is fixed by default in the scroll_box function. What i would like to do now is fix the row names as well, so that when I scroll sideways I can always see them. Is there a way to do that (using R markdown - I don't want to have to go digging in the html directly if that can be avoided)?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way of doing this with `kableExtra` but you could try `DT` with the `FixedColumns` extension. See [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using datatable does let me fix the rownames :) I'm looking now to fix (along with the header) the first row of data under the header... do you by chance know how that can be done?